# What does it mean to share internals with an immutable object in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I have been reading Effective Java and I have come across the statement that not only can you share immutable objects, but you can share their internals. But, I am struggling to figure out what that *really* means and an example would surely help as no example is given in the book. I already know that immutable objects can't be changed, such as a `String`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the [book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=not+only+can+you+share+immutable+objects,+but+you+can+share+their+internals.&source=bl&ots=yYJhLfu5PY&sig=zzjMccye4ELadcHtUzam0_U7xe4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hujLUY-0J8fRrQfnwYCwCQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=not%20only%20can%20you%20share%20immutable%20objects%2C%20but%20you%20can%20share%20their%20internals.&f=false) further:

> The `BigInteger` class uses a sign-magnitude representation internally. The sign is represented by an `int` and the magnitude is represented by an `int` array. The `negate` method produces a new `BigInteger` of like magnitude and opposite sign. **It does not need to copy the array; the newly created `BigInteger` points to the same internal array as original.**

Answer (score 6):

For example if you have a class

```
public class Vector2d { 
  private final BigDecimal a;
  private final BigDecimal b;
}
```

Then `a` and `b` are the "internals" of that class. Since this are instance of `BigDecimal` they are immutable. If you implement an operation like `setBToZero()` you can simply reuse your instance of `a` and don't have to recreate a new one. For example

```
public Vector2d setBToZero() { 
  return new Vector2d(a, 0);
}
```

You share your internal `a` and since it is immutable you don't have to worry about changes of your shared state. This is especially useful, when it comes to large objects. If you use interfaces you can implement some operations only by using proxy objects.

Comment: The "shared internals" comment deals more with the scenario where the shared item is an instance of a *mutable* type (typically an array) which holders would be "physically capable" of modifying, but contractually forbidden to modify.  Immutable types are inherently sharable, and instances which can mutate are non-sharable.  Between those are instances which are capable of mutation, but which will not in fact ever mutate.

Answer (score 0):

I think what they're really saying is that normally with mutable objects you would access and modify fields with getter and setter methods and synchronous these in a multithreaded environment. However, with immutable objects as these fields are guaranteed to always be the same you're completely safe making them `public` and "exposing" and "sharing" them. Which is good - accessing a public field can be clearer and more efficient than calling a method.

Comment: You've got a point, but that's not what "sharing internals" means: an *internal* is by definition state which is not publicly accessible. So "sharing" is between instances of the same class.

Comment: Seeing others answers I now see what "sharing" meant in the context of the question. I was reading it as sharing objects between threads. Silly ambiguous English language.

Answer (score 0):

An example of sharing internals of immutable objects. Data is immutable, it shares its byte array with other immutable instances of Data.

```
public final class Data {

    private byte[] data; 
    private int start;
    private int end;

    private Data(byte[] data, int start, int end) {
        this.data = data;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public Data(byte[] data) {
        this(Arrays.copyOf(data), 0, data.length - 1); // copy so nobody can access our array
    }

    public Data lowerHalf() {
        return new Data(this.data, 0, data.length / 2);  // sharing byte array
    }

    public byte get(int index) {
        return data[start + index];
    }         
}
```